# unexpected argument '-c' found

Tags: docker, surrealdb

I'm using this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/surrealdb/surrealdb.). I assume this is the official one.

Following the basic instructions from that page I have an instance with either of the two example commands
`docker run --rm --pull always --name surrealdb -p 8000:8000 surrealdb/surrealdb:latest start`

or

`docker run --rm --pull always --name surrealdb -p 8000:8000 surrealdb/surrealdb:latest start --log trace --user root --pass root memory`

However, when I attempt to use the example command to access the CLI

`docker exec -it <COPIED_FROM_DOCKER> /surreal sql -c http://localhost:8000 -u root -p root --ns test --db test --pretty`

I get the above error `unexpected argument '-c' found`

I have looked at the [official documentation](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/installation/running/docker) but I see no example of trying to use the docker exec command.

Is the documentation in docker hub incorrect? I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.2.

Comment: I have not figured out a way around this error. However, somehow I accidentally installed the surreal cli... I'm not sure how that happened but it works well and the documentation on the official site is easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first using `docker exec -it <container_name> sh` or similar, then try running `/surreal sql ...`. This will help you to see if there is a problem with your `docker exec` invocation, or with the command.

My gut instinct is that the command is the problem, and that you should be using

```
docker exec -it <COPIED_FROM_DOCKER> surreal sql --endpoint http://localhost:8000 -u root -p root --ns test --db test --pretty
```

per the documentation here: https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/cli/sql#example-usage

The differences there are:

- use `surreal`, not `/surreal`
- use `--endpoint`, not `-c`.

(I think that the documentation in Docker hub has a typo, and should have `-e`, not `-c` -- the two look quite similar at a glance.)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I was curious about swapping the -c with -e or --endpoint. I have tried your suggestions above but when running "docker exect -it #### sh" or replace 'sh' with 'bin/sh' or 'bin/bash' I get the following error "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown"